# what is the one-dimensional counterpart to the green-gauss theorem?

Tags: integration, greens-theorem, divergent-integrals

Are my answers to a and b correct?

a) In a three-dimensional situation, the spatial variation of a scalar field is given by the gradient. What is the one-dimensional counterpart? Answer:The derivative

b) In a three-dimensional situation, a volume integral of a divergence of a vector field can be transformed into a surface integral (Gauss’s theorem). What is the one-dimensional counterpart? answer: Integration by parts

I have searched for this question but I can't find the right answer to question c. Can anyone help me?

c) What is the one-dimensional counterpart to the Green-Gauss theorem?

Comment: Green's theorem is a special case of Stokes's theorem, whose one-dimensional counterpart is the fundamental theorem of calculus. They all relate the integral of a function in the interior of a region to the values on its boundary.

Comment: I really don’t understand, can you explain more please?

Comment: To get you started, it might help to think carefully about what regions these integrals are over. In three dimensions you can turn the integral over a volumetric region into the integral over just the "edge" or "boundary" of that region. What does a region look like in 1d? What does its boundary?

Comment: 1D is a line, or a vector in 2D or 3D space, defined by two coordinates. A line or border around the outside of a shape. It defines the space or area. That is what boundary does, I think

Comment: Is my answer correct now?           a) In a three-dimensional situation, the spatial variation of a scalar field is given by the gradient. What is the one-dimensional counterpart? Answer: The derivative

b) In a three-dimensional situation, a volume integral of a divergence of a vector field can be transformed into a surface integral (Gauss’s theorem). What is the one-dimensional counterpart? answer: Integrals and antiderivatives
c) What is the one-dimensional counterpart to the Green-Gauss theorem? Integration by parts